telethon except UserPrivacyRestrictedError dont work
When I select mode 3 and the script tries to give admin rights to a user with private settings, everything works.
But when I select mode 1, it doesn't work, it just writes that the user is added.
I've read the documentation, but I haven't found an answer as to why this happens with mode one.

        for user in users:
            n += 1
            if n > invite_limit:
                print(GREEN + f"[!] Аккаунт {inviter_name} достиг лимита приглашений ({invite_limit}).")
                break

            if n % 50 == 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(50, 75))

            try:
                if user['username'] == "":
                    continue

                elif mode == 1:
                    user_to_add = await client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
                    await client(InviteToChannelRequest(
                        target_group_entity,
                        [user_to_add], 
                    ))
                    print(f" Добавлен {GREEN}{user['username']}{RESET} аккаунтом {CYAN}{inviter_name}{RESET}")  
                    print(f"{yl}[+] {inviter_name} - Перекур минутку...")
                    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(60, 75))

                elif mode == 3:
                    user_to_add = await client.get_input_entity(user['username'])
                    admin_rights = ChatAdminRights(
                        delete_messages=True,
                        edit_messages=True,
                        ban_users=True,
                        invite_users=True,
                        pin_messages=True
                    )
                    await client(EditAdminRequest(
                        target_group_entity,
                        user_to_add,
                        admin_rights=admin_rights,
                        rank='admin'
                    ))
                    await asyncio.sleep(2)
                    await client(EditAdminRequest(
                        target_group_entity,
                        user_to_add,
                        rank='',
                        admin_rights=ChatAdminRights(),
                    ))
                    print(f" Назначен админом {GREEN}{user['username']}{RESET} аккаунтом {CYAN}{inviter_name}{RESET}")
                    await asyncio.sleep(30)

            except ValueError:
                print(RED + "[!] Пользователь с идентификатором {} не найден. Пропуск.".format(user['id']), RESET)
                continue
            except PeerFloodError as pfe:
                print(f"{RED}[!] Получено сообщение о Флуде от Telegram\n[!] Скрипт, остановит инвайт для {CYAN}{inviter_name}{RESET}\n[!] Попробуйте позже")
                sleep_accounts.append(inviter_name)
                break
            except UserPrivacyRestrictedError:
                print(RED + f"[!] Ошибка: Приватные настройки пользователя не позволяют выполнить это действие." + RESET)
                await asyncio.sleep(30)
                continue
            except Exception as e:
                print(RED + f"[!] Неожиданная ошибка {CYANM}{inviter_name}{RESET}: {e}")
                await asyncio.sleep(30)
                continue

    except ValueError as ve:
        print(RED + "[!] Ошибка: " + str(ve) + RESET)
    except Exception as e:
        print(RED + "[!] Неожиданная ошибка: " + str(e) + RESET)


